# different height to li tag

Tags: javascript, html

i want to Design Menu bar as shown below, i have created whole list in ul but how to set different height ,width for center .Please help i tried code below but middle part is not increasing,

```
<nav id="Edit_panel">
            <ul>
                <li class="menubar" title="redo">
                    <div id="link">redo</div>
                </li>
                <li class="menubar" title="undo">
                    <div id="link">undo</div>
                </li>
                <li class="menubar" title="cut">
                    <div id="link">Cut</div>
                </li>
                <li class="menubar" title="copy">
                    <div id="link">Copy</div>
                </li>
                <li class="menubar" title="paste">
                    <div id="link">paste</div>
                </li>

                <li class="menubar" title="select">
                    <div id="link">select</div>
                </li>
                <li class="menubar" title="hand">
                    <div id="link">hand</div>
                </li>
                <li class="menubar" title="zoomin">
                    <div id="link">zoomin</div>
                </li>
                <li class="menubar" title="zoomout">
                    <div id="link">zoomout</div>
                </li>
                <li class="menubar" title="addimage">
                    <div id="link">Add img</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

css:

```
    #Edit_panel {
    background-color: gray;
    height:25px;
    display: inline;
}

ul
{
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    height:30px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code you tried, rather than the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot have multiple elements with the same id, so you should change all

```
id = "link"
```

to

```
class = "link"
```

or delete those id's

---

Another mistake is putting height to the ul in css. The 30px height of ul means, that you want the whole list to be 30px high. You want to define the height for li elements, not the whole ul.

Instead of:

```
ul
{
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    height:30px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center
}
```

Should be:

```
ul
{
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
li {
    height:30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center
}
```

---

If you want some elements to have different height or width, you can add some class to them, and define height for the class, for example:

```
<li class="menubar higher" title="paste">
    <div id="link">paste</div>
</li>
```

And then in CSS you add:

```
.higher {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Then your elements will be 30px high, and elements witch also have "higher" class, will he higher than others;]

Answer (score 0):

Just add another class to elements You want to increase and set diferent height.
And remove duplicated ids.

Answer (score 0):

you can give different heights to your elements by jquery. Use this demo for it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<style>
.test
{
    height:25px;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("li").eq(5).addClass("test"); // In 'eq' 5 is a index of li element and it starts from 0 to n-1
});
</script>
```